# Determine % of overlap of two networks within a certain distance (e.g. 1km)

Tags: qgis

I'm a beginner to GIS analysis.

I have two shapefiles with two networks and would like to calculate the % of overlap within a certain distance (1km).

How can I do this kind of analysis using QGIS?

Comment: Would you like us to give you a nudge in the right direction or lay out how this process should be completed?

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Calculate lengths for both networks (`$length` in the field calculator) and sum it up (copy & paste the attributes to excel)

Step 2: Buffer both layers with 1.000 m

Step 3: Clip one buffer with the other in order to obtain intersecting areas

Step 4: Clip both networks with the product of step 3

Step 5: Redo step 1 for the cropped networks

Step 6: Compare new lenghts to old lengths.